# Why does gamma show up in the relativistic velocity equations in the $y$ and $z$ terms?

Tags: special-relativity, velocity, inertial-frames, observers

I understand the addition of velocities in relativity in terms of the $x$ direction is

$$u_x=\frac{v+u_x'}{1+vu_x'/c^2}$$

What I don't understand is why, when calculating for the $y$ and $z$ directions, $\gamma$ (gamma) becomes involved.

$$u_y=\frac{u'_y}{\gamma(1+vu_x'/c^2)}$$

$$u_z=\frac{u'_z}{\gamma(1+vu_x'/c^2)}$$

Maybe I just haven't studied enough on the topic but any explanation would help.

Comment: The effect on transverse components has to do with the transformation of the time coordinate.

Comment: It's because the movement of an object through space at a fixed speed of light, affects the phase velocity of the wave in all directions (the change in phase velocity is actually directional-dependent, but the round-trip velocity is isotropic and will be seen as a uniform reduction in velocity in all directions).

Answer (score 2):

As secavara pointed out, thinking naively about it, if you have velocity with respect to a reference frame (this is a spatial coordinate system and a clock),  your clock will tic at a different rate from that of the reference system. And since velocity is computed by dividing the space traveled between the time spent, it is reasonable to think that the transverse directions respect to the velocity will also be affected.

Mathematically, we can choose spatio-temporal coordinates in Minkowski space as: $x^\mu = (ct,x,y,z) = (ct,\vec{x})$, where $\mu$ goes from $0$ to 3: $0$ for the temporal component, $ct$, and 1, 2 and 3 for $x, y \text{ and } z$. This is the position four-vector. $\vec{x}$ is the ordinary position vector.

In order to derive the velocity we have to take the derivative, but with respect to what time?, well, if you have some velocity respect to me, and I want to compute *your* velocity, its fairly resonable that I take the derivative with respect to *your* time, i.e. the time measured by your clock. This is the *proper time*$, \tau$. So let's do it:

\begin{equation}
 u^\mu=\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}=\left( c\frac{dt}{d\tau},\frac{d\vec{x}}{d\tau} \right),
\end{equation}

but then by the chain rule:

\begin{equation}
\frac{d\vec{x}}{d\tau} = \frac{d\vec{x}}{dt} \frac{dt}{d\tau} 
\end{equation}

And since, $\gamma = dt/d\tau$, and $\vec{v} = d\vec{x}/dt$, we have:

\begin{equation}
 u^\mu=\frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}=\left( \gamma c,\gamma\vec{v} \right),
\end{equation}

Hope I have helped!

**EDIT:** I had to run and didn't had time to finish, here are a few last thoughts.

So, if I want to know how *you* see (the components of) a four-vector $w'^{\mu}$ (the four-position for example, but also the four-momentum or any other four-vector), I would Lorentz transform (boost) the components I see, $w^\mu$ , using *your* velocity, $\vec{v}$.

Since we are transforming a vector (rigorously the contravariant components of a vector), the transformation is accomplished contracting (multiplying) the components of the Lorentz boost tensor (matrix), in the direction of your velocity (say it is the positive $x$ direction for simplicity), $\underset{x}{\Lambda}{}^\mu_{~~\nu}$, with (the components of) my four-vector $w^{\mu}$, using Einstein's summation convention, this yields:

\begin{equation}
  \underset{(you)}{w'^{\mu}} = \underset{x}{\Lambda}{}^\mu_{~~\nu}\underset{(me)}{w^{\nu}}
\end{equation}

or in matrix notation:

\begin{equation}
\left[ \begin{array}{c} w'^0\\w'^1\\w'^2\\w'^3 \end{array} \right] = \begin{bmatrix} \gamma & -\gamma\beta & 0& 0 \\ -\gamma\beta & \gamma & 0& 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1& 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0& 1 \end{bmatrix} \times \left[ \begin{array}{c} w^0\\w^1\\w^2\\w^3 \end{array} \right]
\end{equation}

where $\beta=v/c$. If for example, $w$ was the four-position of some event we would have:

\begin{equation}
\left[ \begin{array}{c} ct'\\x'\\y'\\z' \end{array} \right] = \begin{bmatrix} \gamma & -\gamma\beta & 0& 0 \\ -\gamma\beta & \gamma & 0& 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1& 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0& 1 \end{bmatrix} \times \left[ \begin{array}{c} ct\\x\\y\\z \end{array} \right]
\end{equation}

and we recover the more familiar expressions for the lorentz transformations of each spatio-temporal component as Joseph points out.

Last but not least I want to emphasize that four-vectors, $\boldsymbol{v}$ don't change under coordinate transformations, what changes are the **components** of the vector, $v^\mu$, because these are obtained projecting the four-vector onto the coordinate axes of the reference frame.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, velocity is $\frac{distance}{time}$. For $u_x$, both $x$ and $t$ are transformed with a $\gamma$ factor, so they cancel out. For $u_y$ and $u_z$ the $\gamma$ exists in the $t$ transformation but not in the $y$ and $z$ transformations, leading to a leftover $\gamma$ in the denominator.

More precisely, If Observer $B$ has velocity $v$ purely in the $x$ direction relative to Observer $A$, then the Lorentz transformations from $A$ to $B$ are as follows:

$$t' = \gamma(t - \frac{vx}{c^2})$$
$$x' = \gamma(x - vt)$$
$$y' = y$$
$$z' = z$$

If Observer $A$ observes an object going at velocity $u = (\frac{dx}{dt}, \frac{dy}{dt}, \frac{dz}{dt})$, then Observer $B$ will observe:

$$u_x' = \frac{dx'}{dt'} = \frac{\gamma(dx - vdt)}{\gamma(dt - \frac{vdx}{c^2})} = \frac{dx - vdt}{dt - \frac{vdx}{c^2}} = \frac{\frac{dx}{dt} - v}{1 - \frac{v\frac{dx}{dt}}{c^2}} = \frac{u_x - v}{1 - \frac{v u_x}{c^2}}$$ 
$$u_y' = \frac{dy'}{dt'} = \frac{dy}{\gamma(dt - \frac{vdx}{c^2})} = \frac{u_y}{\gamma(1 - \frac{vu_x}{c^2})}$$
$$u_z' = \frac{dz'}{dt'} = \frac{dz}{\gamma(dt - \frac{vdx}{c^2})} = \frac{u_z}{\gamma(1 - \frac{vu_x}{c^2})}$$

Reverse these equations and you will get yours.

Answer (score 0):

To make algebra simple, suppose the body goes at constant velocity from (0, 0, 0, 0) in the S system (and therefore (0, 0, 0. 0) in the S' system) to ($t,\ x,\ y,\ z)$ in the S system, that is ($t',\ x',\ y',\ z')$ in S'. Then, using the Lorentz transforms for transverse displacement and time: 
$$u'_y=\frac{y'}{t'}=\frac{y}{\gamma \left(t-\frac{v\ x}{c^2}\right)}=\frac{u_y}{\gamma \left(1-\frac{v\ u_x}{c^2}\right)}.$$The last step was simply division top and bottom by $t$.